# Does *Mathematica* have $\varphi$?

Tags: formatting

I know I can input

```
\[Phi]
```

...to get $\phi$ in the *Mathematica* front end, but is there a way to get $\varphi$?

Comment: If you enter "phi" in the help search input field, you get a number of phi-character hits (5 in the top 10).  If you click on `\[Phi]`, the top one, you will see a link to `\[CurlyPhi]` just below the character image.  Click & explore. :)

Comment: I am inclined to reopen this question since the best answer is clearly not "easily found" in the documentation. Mathematica notebooks support [Latex aliases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-ListingOfNamedCharacters.html#19728).  So if you know that you would get the character you want in LaTeX as `\varphi`, you can just enter it in a notebook as `[esc]\varphi[esc]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\[CurlyPhi]
```

will give you φ, or `Esc` j `Esc`

Answer (score 7):

use ESC j ESC to get curly PHI

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is in Palettes->Basic typesetting-> special characters

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.